# Who wins Higher flush or Straight + Flush

Tags: rules, reading-hands

[image]

1st hand: Q♣️ K♠️
2nd hand: 7♦️ 6♠️
Table: Q♠️ 5♣️ 4♠️ 8♠️ 10♠️

Who wins this??

Answer (score 1):

K♠️ Q♠️ T♠️ 8♠️ 4♠️ >  Q♠️ T♠️ 8♠️ 6♠️ 4♠️

The higher flush wins.

This is because the second hand is qualified as just a flush. You need a Straight and flush in the same 5 cards for it to be called a Straight flush.

All players make the best 5 card hand that they can using the 7 cards they have access to.

Answer (score 0):

1st hand wins, this picture might be helpful for You [poker hand ranking](https://www.cardschat.com/pkimg/hand-nicknames/poker-hand-rankings.png)